# Can the coordinates of a 2 dimensional pytorch tensor be remapped?

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch

I'm trying to remap a 2d image to new coordinates. Previously I was using OpenCV's [cv.remap](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gab75ef31ce5cdfb5c44b6da5f3b908ea4) method. I'd like to use CUDA with compiling C directly. Is there a Pytorch version of remap that will interpolate values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for [`grid_sample`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#grid-sample)?
Look for make_grid function for additional information